# Non-recursive factorial in Ruby

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

I've implemented a factorial function in a more "Ruby" way. I would like to get feedback on the algorithm.

```
def factorial_of n
  (1..n).inject :*
end

factorial_of 5
=> 120
```

Comment: `factorial_of 5` gives 15, not 120... Maybe you had another function and didn't paste in the correct one?

Comment: So sorry! Just edited. I pasted it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "of" in the name `factorial_of` is redundant and unconventional.

`factorial_of 0` returns `nil` instead of [the correct answer, which is `1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Factorial_of_zero).

```
def factorial(n)
  (1..n).inject(1, :*)
end
```